# Issue whilst trying to read in a seperated text file - Python

Tags: python, enumerate

I am new to python however trying to get my head around CSV, I have managed to get a text file split into the data that I want and am able to output the data to screen and it is as I need it. However, I cannot get each line of data to do exactly what I want.

Below is the code that I have so far.

```
g = Name()
map(g.add_vertex, ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6'])
with open('file.txt', "r") as file:
for row_index, row in enumerate(file):
    for col_index, value in enumerate(row.split(",")):
        b = int(value)
        if b != 0:
            g.do_something(row_index,col_index, b)
```

My output for this is ( snippet ) being read from a text file, showing row, column and data ( if I have a print function before the g.do_something(row, col, data) line.

```
0 1 2
0 2 4
0 3 1
0 4 6
1 0 2
1 4 5
```

My issue is that I cannot get it to read into the g.do_something(row, col, data) with each line being separate, it seems to only add the last line of the separated values when I do a print of it after the g.do_something(row, col, data) line.
I am not sure how you can iterate through so that each would be separated.
The whole program or more of the code can be added if needed.
Many thanks for your time.

Comment: where is `col` defined? The first time it appears in your code is on the last line. By the way, manually parsing CSV is dangerous - consider using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv) module instead.

Comment: sorry, error on my part, has now been edited

Comment: You should do as @Kevin says and use the csv module. Could you add the definition of Name, and a couple of lines of data from the csv file?